# How can I write a check with no exact amount but with an upper bound in the United States?

Tags: united-states, check

I live in the United States. I'd like to write a check to someone. I don't know the exact amount yet    but I do know the upper bound. How can I write a check with no exact amount but with an upper bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Los Angeles County clerk](https://lavote.gov/docs/rrcc/documents/NTE.pdf?v=2) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220424202909/https://lavote.gov/docs/rrcc/documents/NTE.pdf?v=2)) suggests one can write a check with no exact amount but with an upper bound by indicating a "Not To Exceed X USD" on the memo line of the check:

[image]

I [don't know](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/79612/31) if this is legally binding.

Comment: This is not legally binding, same as "valid for XXX days" is not legally binding. If the check is presented, the bank will ignore this.

Comment: @littleadv thanks, you are welcome to convert your comment into an answer on  https://law.stackexchange.com/q/79612/31

Comment: @littleadv: Assuming UCC 3-407 was adopted by the relevant jurisdiction: It is legally binding on the recipient, but not on the bank.  Per [UCC § 3-407](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/3/3-407), modifying an "incomplete instrument" (i.e., a check without the dollar amount filled in) without consent of the person who wrote it is illegal.  Per 3-407-c, the bank can cash such checks, unless they realize the check was modified fraudulently.  A teller who notices a violated NTE line probably should reject the check.  However, more often than not the bank will ignore the memo line.

Answer (score 2):

The check is your commitment to pay to the order of the `payee` the $`amount`, signed by your hand.

Nothing else written on the check matters.

Your link refers to the NTE checks *issued or received* by the LA county, and the rules for these checks apply to the county itself, not the banks ([source](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/not-to-exceed-amount)).